# modernizr with the build on angular 5

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular5

I have a custom build with [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/download/#-fontface-backgroundsize-borderimage-borderradius-boxshadow-flexbox-hsla-multiplebgs-opacity-rgba-textshadow-cssanimations-csscolumns-generatedcontent-cssgradients-cssreflections-csstransforms-csstransforms3d-csstransitions-applicationcache-canvas-canvastext-draganddrop-hashchange-history-audio-video-indexeddb-input-inputtypes-localstorage-postmessage-sessionstorage-websockets-websqldatabase-webworkers-geolocation-inlinesvg-smil-svg-svgclippaths-touch-webgl-shiv-cssclasses-addtest-prefixed-teststyles-testprop-testallprops-hasevent-prefixes-domprefixes-load) and I have problems with build on angular 5, without build everything works perfectly. I enter this js in the script section in `.angular-cli.json`

The error that I have when make the build is the next:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'html5' of undefined
    at scripts.b43496ed343a01b5b3b7.bundle.js:11
    at scripts.b43496ed343a01b5b3b7.bundle.js:11
    at scripts.b43496ed343a01b5b3b7.bundle.js:11
```

And the only place where I handle the variable html5 is in modernzr. Also noticed that in the build the variables are different from the current code within the .js script of modernizr.

[image]

this is the image of the error. and code look diferent:

```
var options = window.html5 || {};
var reSkip = /^<|^(?:button|map|select|textarea|object|iframe|option|optgroup)$/i;
var saveClones = /^(?:a|b|code|div|fieldset|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6|i|label|li|ol|p|q|span|strong|style|table|tbody|td|th|tr|ul)$/i;
var supportsHtml5Styles;
var expando = '_html5shiv';
var expanID = 0;
var expandoData = {};
var supportsUnknownElements;
```